# Reshaping a Dataframe, pivoting and expanding column by group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Apologies if this is a duplicate - I can't seem to find the right keywords to get the hits I want.

Provided I have a similar `DataFrame` as such:

```
  name desc   class   group subgroup
0  abc   _d  class1  group1      sg1
1  def   _g  class1  group1      sg1
2  ghi   _j  class1  group1      sg2
3  jkl   _m  class1  group1      sg2
4  mno   _p  class2  group2      sg1
5  pqr   _s  class2  group2      sg1
6  stu   _v  class2  group2      sg2
7  vwx   _y  class2  group2      sg2
```

Ultimately, I want to reshape the frame to something like below:

```
   class   group subgroup  name1  desc1 name2 desc2
0 class1  group1      sg1    abc     _d   def    _g
1 class1  group1      sg2    ghi     _j   jkl    _m
2 class2  group2      sg1    mno     _p   pqr    _s
3 class2  group2      sg2    stu     _v   vwx    _y
```

Less ideally, even in a list format (which I can split later if need be):

```
   class   group subgroup         name      desc
0 class1  group1      sg1   [abc, def]  [_d, _g]
1 class1  group1      sg2   [ghi, jkl]  [_j, _m]
2 class2  group2      sg1   [mno, pqr]  [_p, _s]
3 class2  group2      sg2   [stu, vwx]  [_v, _y]
```

I tried to use `df.pivot(index=['class','group','subgroup'],columns=['name','desc'])`, but obviously that doesn't work because it doesn't expand the columns.  It just gives me a `ValueError`:

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected 8 rows, received array of length 3
```

I can use `df.groupby(['class', 'group', 'subgroup']).sum()` but it mangles up the `name`/`desc`:

```
                          name  desc
class  group  subgroup              
class1 group1 sg1       abcdef  _d_g
              sg2       ghijkl  _j_m
class2 group2 sg1       mnopqr  _p_s
              sg2       stuvwx  _v_y
```

I can probably do this in several steps, but I'm wondering if there's an obvious solution that I'm completely missing?

Comment: Thanks for the dupe link, it turns out to be the same method I used anyhow for the first step.  Since I'm looking to also expand the `list` itself to columns, I'll let the community decide whether this is a full duplicate.

Comment: With the answer you gave, it makes the dup not really valid :) but your answer seems to assume there will be always 2 elements in each column per group of class, group and subgroup?

Comment: @Ben.T Thanks for that question - I was pretty sure the columns would only have 2 rows in each group but turns out there are some outliers that have 1, 3 or 4 rows.  The intent remains the same (so I guess there should be 4 columns each for `name` and `desc` now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to create the final 1, 2, .. in the columns name. Then `set_index` and `unstack`. If you don't want a multiindex columns, then flatten it:

```
df_f = df.assign(cc=df.groupby(['class', 'group', 'subgroup']).cumcount()+1)\
         .set_index(['class', 'group', 'subgroup', 'cc']).unstack()

# if you don't want the multiindex columns
df_f.columns = [f'{col[0]}{col[1]}' for col in df_f.columns]

print (df_f)
                       name1 name2 desc1 desc2
class  group  subgroup                        
class1 group1 sg1        abc   def    _d    _g
              sg2        ghi   jkl    _j    _m
class2 group2 sg1        mno   pqr    _p    _s
              sg2        stu   vwx    _v    _y
```

Answer (score 2):

this was trickier than I expected. The basic idea is to `.apply(list)` to the grouped columns. However I wasn't able to select multiple columns at once after the `groupby`. For this reason I used a list comprehension, and concatenate the resulting two series with `pd.concat(axis=1)`. This could be also a one liner however I think it lacks readability if done in one line

```
selects = ['desc','name']
list_of_series = [so.groupby(['class', 'group', 'subgroup'])[val].apply(list) for val in selects]
so_new = pd.concat(list_of_series,axis=1)
```

output

```
                            desc        name
class  group  subgroup                      
class1 group1 sg1       [_d, _g]  [abc, def]
              sg2       [_j, _m]  [ghi, jkl]
class2 group2 sg1       [_p, _s]  [mno, pqr]
              sg2       [_v, _y]  [stu, vwx]
```

---

The not advised one liner

```
so_new2 = pd.concat([so.groupby(['class', 'group', 'subgroup'])[val].apply(list) for val in ['desc','name']],axis=1)
```

---

### Updated Answer

```
selects = ['desc', 'name']
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(lst.values.tolist(),columns=[selects[ii]+"1",selects[ii]+"2"],index=lst.index) \
                  for ii,lst in enumerate([so.groupby(['class', 'group', 'subgroup'])[val].apply(list) \
                                           for val in selects])],axis=1)
```

Output

```
                       desc1 desc2 name1 name2
class  group  subgroup                        
class1 group1 sg1         _d    _g   abc   def
              sg2         _j    _m   ghi   jkl
class2 group2 sg1         _p    _s   mno   pqr
              sg2         _v    _y   stu   vwx
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my question, I was able to achieve this through several steps:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['class','group','subgroup'], values=['name','desc'], aggfunc=list)

#                             desc        name
# class  group  subgroup                      
# class1 group1 sg1       [_d, _g]  [abc, def]
#               sg2       [_j, _m]  [ghi, jkl]
# class2 group2 sg1       [_p, _s]  [mno, pqr]
#               sg2       [_v, _y]  [stu, vwx]

df = df.reset_index()

# Create new columns and join it back
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.desc.to_list(), columns=['desc0','desc1']))
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.name.to_list(), columns=['name0','name1']))

# Remove the superfluous listed columns
df.drop(['desc','name'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

---

Result:

```
    class   group subgroup desc0 desc1 name0 name1
0  class1  group1      sg1    _d    _g   abc   def
1  class1  group1      sg2    _j    _m   ghi   jkl
2  class2  group2      sg1    _p    _s   mno   pqr
3  class2  group2      sg2    _v    _y   stu   vwx
```

Ideally I'd still prefer fewer steps and wondering if a better approach exists.

Comment: I edited my answer. Not sure if it is really better. As the list comprehensions got out of hand quickly. However it does what you asked in just one step

Comment: @BjörnB appreciate the update.  I'm a fan of list comprehension but with `pandas`, it's almost always better to rely on its native method and avoid list comps and `apply`s.  When I wanted a simpler answer I didn't necessarily meant less lines... more if there are other combinations of methods (e.g. `explode`, `melt`) that I'm missing.  That one-liner is interesting though, I'm going to disseminate it a bit.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah apologies for that - I should have made that clearer.

Comment: I contacted someone. If there is a proper solution to this he will know.